# do websockets work in mobile apps without connecting to a browser?

Tags: android, iphone, html, cordova, websocket

I am writing an app in native html/css/javascript which has to work on almost every main mobile platform. I am using websockets for client-server communication.
I have tested on pc and it works perfectly, but i do not know if it works on mobile devices(iphone,android, etc)
without using a browser.

Comment: A socket is a socket. You can definitely open a socket on iOS using the BSD sockets API, and I assume that there is a similar function on android.

Comment: I am asking just for websockets because these sockets allow the communication from javascript to php as well which is very important in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CanIUse.com is a great site for this type of question.

http://caniuse.com/#search=websocket

Sadly, websockets are not implemented on Android. There may be a plugin for PhoneGap Android but I have not used one.